# Finding the probability that the first ace appears on the $(n + 1)$st draw

Tags: probability, combinations

Cards are dealt one by one from a well-shuffled pack until an ace appears. Show that the probability that exactly $n$ cards are dealt before the first ace appears.

**My attempt:** For an ace card to appear after $n$ cards
$$\text{No. of ways }= \, ^{48}C_n \times \, ^{4}C_1$$
$\text{Sample space }= \, ^{52}C_{n+1}$ or should I take $\, ^{52}C_n \times \, ^{52-n}C_1$ but why?

$$\Pr(E) = \, \dfrac{^{48}C_n \times \, ^{4}C_1}{\, ^{52}C_{n+1}}$$

Comment: Or it is just because I have done same thing in the numerator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ takes the values $0, 1, \ldots , 48$

$$P(X=0)= \frac {4}{52} $$
$$P(X=1)= \frac {48}{52} \frac{4}{51} $$
$$P(X=2)= \frac {48}{52} \frac{47}{51} \frac{4}{50}$$
etc.

Thus

$$ P(X=n)= \frac {\frac {4(48!)}{(48-n)!}}{\frac{52!}{(52-n-1)!}} =\frac{{48\choose n}{4\choose 1}}{{52\choose n}{52-n\choose 1}}$$

Comment: You have answered the question correctly...but I am asking what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: No it should be 52Cn*52-nC1...

Comment: But why not 52Cn+1?

Comment: @Akulsharma The sample space is first choosing $n$ cards of the $52$, then the permutations of the remaining $52-n$ cards.

Comment: @ThePhenotype or it is just we have done the same thing in the numerator

Comment: @Akulsharma It's to make up for the combinations in the numerator yes, because the order of cards *does* matter, that's why I wouldn't dare to do this with combinations. If the question doesn't explicitly ask you to use combinatorics, I recommend you calculate these type of questions like in this answer instead of using combinatorics.

Comment: I know it should be done using multiplication rule...but this time i was trying to do it using different approach..and got stuck..